# UNDO and REDO in ACE editor

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ace-editor

I am using ACE editor in a project. But I have an issue with UNDO and REDO. It works with keyboard shortcuts (ctrl + z and ctrl +y) but it is not working when want to do it with right click and than click undo or redo!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZLIN.png)

Comment: Which browser and which version of ace are you using. It works with chrome on latest version here https://ace.c9.io/

Comment: I am using chrome. and "vue2-ace-editor": "0.0.15"

Comment: It is using an outdated version of ace.